# Remove "\r" from a remote RHEL 9 output

Tags: linux

When I run a command on a remote RHEL 9 machine, the output string starts with "\r", which is odd because the output of the same command on several remote RHEL 8 machines doesn't starts with "\r".

For example, when I run the command "echo 'hey'", the output on my remote RHEL 9 machine is "hey", but on my local machine is "\rhey".

I've tried to play with PS0-4 attributes on .bashrc file, but nothing seems to work.

How can I manipulate the output on my RHEL 9 machine so it wouldn't do that?

(The main purpose is to create a template for my RHEL 9 machine in SpecFlow automation)

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running the command? It sounds like you're using `ssh` with the `-T` option, which uses a pseudo-tty. That causes newline to be converted to CRLF.

Comment: From what I've seen, the program is using a third-party SSH client, and I've tried to find any use of "-T" option, but couldn't find any.
But even if I do, how come it only happens on RHEL 9 and not on RHEL 8?
Is there any way to config the RHEL 9 machine to prevent that?

Comment: Does it output a _literal_ "\r" (i.e. backslash and 'r') or does it output an actual CR (carriage return)?

Comment: The output starts with "\r".
I've checked the output value on Visual Studio on debug, and the value is "\r<Value>".
The logger is printing it with a CR.

Comment: Anyway, just pipe the output through `tr -d '\r'`

Comment: @Barmar Can it be done using the .cashrc file, or any other way in the RHEL machine itself?

Comment: This is almost certainly a transformation being done during transmission, not at the source. So you have to remove it after receiving the data.

Comment: I've removed it at my local machine, but I've tried to see if there's any way to change the configuration of the RHEL machine (as a template) to insure it won't happen in any other method, connecting to the RHEL machine.
If there isn't any way to do so, then I'm cool with that.